# A^k for matrix multiplication in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose **A** is some square matrix. How can I easily exponentiate this matrix in R?

I tried two ways already: Trial 1 with a for-loop hack and Trial 2 a bit more elegantly but it is still a far cry from **A**<sup>k</sup> simplicity.

**Trial 1**

```
set.seed(10)
t(matrix(rnorm(16),ncol=4,nrow=4)) -> a 
for(i in 1:2){a <- a %*% a}
```

**Trial 2**

```
a <- t(matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),nrow=4))
i <- diag(4) 
(function(n) {if (n<=1) a else (i+a) %*% Recall(n-1)})(10)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although `Reduce` is more elegant, a for-loop solution is faster and seems to be as fast as expm::%^%

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
m2 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
m3 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
system.time(replicate(1000, Reduce("%*%" , list(m1,m1,m1) ) ) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.026   0.000   0.037 
mlist <- list(m1,m2,m3)
m0 <- diag(1, nrow=3,ncol=3)
system.time(replicate(1000, for (i in 1:3 ) {m0 <- m0 %*% m1 } ) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.013   0.000   0.014 

library(expm)  # and I think this may be imported with pkg:Matrix
system.time(replicate(1000, m0%^%3))
# user  system elapsed 
#0.011   0.000   0.017
```

On the other hand the matrix.power solution is much, much slower:

```
system.time(replicate(1000, matrix.power(m1, 4)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.677   0.013   1.037
```

@BenBolker is correct (yet again). The for-loop appears linear in time as the exponent rises whereas the expm::%^% function appears to be even better than log(exponent).

```
> m0 <- diag(1, nrow=3,ncol=3)
> system.time(replicate(1000, for (i in 1:400 ) {m0 <- m0 %*% m1 } ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.678   0.037   0.708 
> system.time(replicate(1000, m0%^%400))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.006   0.000   0.006
```

Comment: I think `%^%` will have a much greater advantage for larger exponents; I believe it uses a 'doubling' method (i.e. get powers of 2 by multiplying results together, then finish off with a few extra multiplies)

Comment: Instead of `list(m1, m1, m1)`, I'd use `replicate(3, m1, simplify = FALSE)` to make the `Reduce` approach fully extensible

Answer (score 14):

If `A` is diagonizable, you could use eigenvalue decomposition:

```
matrix.power <- function(A, n) {   # only works for diagonalizable matrices
   e <- eigen(A)
   M <- e$vectors   # matrix for changing basis
   d <- e$values    # eigen values
   return(M %*% diag(d^n) %*% solve(M))
}
```

When A is not diagonalizable, the matrix `M` (matrix of eigenvectors) is singular. Thus, using it with `A = matrix(c(0,1,0,0),2,2)` would give `Error in solve.default(M) : system is computationally singular`.

Comment: Yes @flodel, you're right, sorry about that, but it was late in the night, and I was surprised about how many answers here and on other similar duplicate questions were mathematically misleading, thus these words... I'll remove my comment now.

Answer (score 12):

The `expm` package has an `%^%` operator:

```
library("sos")
findFn("{matrix power}")
install.packages("expm")
library("expm")
?matpow
set.seed(10);t(matrix(rnorm(16),ncol=4,nrow=4))->a
a%^%8
```

Comment: This does not compute the matrix raised to some power, but the matrix power exp(M) = I + M + M^2/2! + M^3/3! + ...

Comment: The `expm()` *function* is the matrix exponential, but `%^%` is  a matrix power. e.g. `library(expm); set.seed(101); M <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3); all.equal(M %^% 3, M %*% M %*% M)`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just figured that out and came back to correct my comment, but you beat me to it :-D

Answer (score 4):

Indeed the expm's package does use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

In pure r, this can be done rather efficiently like so,

```
"%^%" <- function(mat,power){
    base = mat
    out = diag(nrow(mat))
    while(power > 1){
        if(power %% 2 == 1){
            out = out %*% base
        }
        base = base %*% base
        power  = power %/% 2
    }
    out %*% base
}
```

Timing this,

```
m0 <- diag(1, nrow=3,ncol=3)
system.time(replicate(10000, m0%^%4000))#expm's %^% function
user  system elapsed 
0.31    0.00    0.31 
system.time(replicate(10000, m0%^%4000))# my %^% function
user  system elapsed 
0.28    0.00    0.28
```

So, as expected, they are the same speed because they use the same algorithm. It looks like the overhead of the looping r code does not make a significant difference.

So, if you don't want to use expm, and need that performance, then you can just use this, if you don't mind looking at imperative code.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter solution with eigenvalue decomposition:

```
"%^%" <- function(S, power)
         with(eigen(S), vectors %*% (values^power * t(vectors)))
```

Comment: Seems wrong: `K<-matrix(1:4,2,2); print(K%^%2);print(K%*%K)`.

Comment: This is wrong indeed. It would work with `t(vectors)` replaced by `solve(vectors)`, but only when the matrix is diagonalizable. Source: linear algebra course.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
`%^%` <- function(A, n) {
  A1 <- A
  for(i in seq_len(n-1)){
    A <- A %*% A1
  }
  return(A)
}
```