# Square a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I've searched and am surprised not to find an answer to the following fairly basic question:

How do you square a matrix in R?  That is to say, for a square matrix $A$ how do I compute $A^{2}$?  Of course I could matrix product it with itself, but if the matrix I want to square has a very long expression, this seems undesirable, and worse if I were to want a higher power.

I heard one person mention the `expm` package while talking about his problem and I suppose I could try this, but it mentioned a bug that I'm not certain has been fixed.  It's also surprising you'd need to import a package to do this pretty basic matrix operation, but maybe that's just how it is.

Comment: I would recommend `expm::%^%`.  Can you point to any concrete information about the putative bug?

Comment: what does "a very long expression" mean? Is this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459421/ak-for-matrix-multiplication-in-r?